# Help needed in using hasClass() to check <div> class in document

Tags: jquery

I a trying to check for DIV class in my document.
But it is not working for me,Please help me..  Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var x=$(this).hasClass('global');
alert(x);
});
```

And even i have tried below code but still same result..

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   var x=$('#global').length;
   alert(x);
  });
```

It is always showing 0..... :-(

Comment: Show your markup and it will be easier to give you the exact selector necessary to select your div correctly.

Comment: now I'm confused are you looking for an id or a class?

Comment: Using #global won't work because # is used to select id's, not classes, and when you use length on a jquery wrapped object, it returns the number of returned objects, so be sure that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want to do but i'll assume you want to know if there is an item in the DOM with the class you specify.

It'd be simpler if you did:

```
var x = $(".global");

alert(x.size());
```

Comment: Thank you ssssssssssssssssoooooooooooooo much boss :-)

Answer (score 3):

`this` is referring to the document you need to refer to a `div` element

```
$('div').hasClass('global')
```

or even simpler:

```
$('div.global')
```

you can then iterate through all of the divs found using the `this` keyword and the e[ach function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$('div.global').each(function(){
    console.log($(this)); // trace out each element found 
});
```

Comment: `$('div.global')` is not only simpler but far more efficient than using `.hasClass()`

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the document has a class of 'global'.  What you want is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var x=$("div.global");
   alert("There is "+x.size()+" divs with class 'global'");
});
```

but if you want to get them all and do something use EACH:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.global").each(function() {
       //do something here
       alert("I have the class global");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your div, not this, to determine if it has the class in question:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="global"></div>

$('#myDiv').hasClass('global');
```

Comment: Why not $('.global') if it has the class instead of using the id?

Comment: @maxfielden what if there is `<li class="global">`

Comment: Because classes can be applied to multiple elements - if you want to select with a class, better to include the element: div.global - selecting with the id here is just to show as an example, but if you're selecting something to determine something specific about it afterwards, you should use a selector that will be specific in what it selects.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` in the `$(document).ready()` refers to the `window` object (do an `alert($(this).get(0))` to see what I mean).

If you want the amount of of `divs` with the `global` class you should do:

```
alert($('div.global').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function()
{
  var x = $("div.global");
  alert(x);
});
```